# Get crash with AlertDialogLayout

Tags: javascript, android, crash, widget

After upgrading sdk to 25 I started to get crash

Here is my peace of code:

```
void showLendAHandDialog(Post post) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("")
                .setMessage(R.string.lend_a_hand)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        createChatRequest(post);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }
```

ERROR:

```
No virtual method getGravity()I in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/AlertDialogLayout; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout')
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onLayout(AlertDialogLayout.java:280)
```

Can't fix it. If anyone faced with similar pls share. Thanks!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Try sync project than clean and rebuild

Comment: @an_droid_dev ok will try thanks!

Comment: @an_droid_dev It helps, thanks))